# Call to function on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I call a function _toggleDropdown or _onWindowClick from another class and file?

**DropDown.js**

```
export default class DropDown extends React.Component {

  _toggleDropdown(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      isActive: !this.state.isActive
    })
  }

  _onWindowClick(event) {
    const dropdownElement = findDOMNode(this)
    if (event.target !== dropdownElement && !dropdownElement.contains(event.target) && this.state.isActive) {
      this.setState({
        isActive: false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Header.js**

```
<a onClick={what???}>test</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DropDown` component is rendered within `Header` you can use `refs` to get dropdown instance and call its methods.

**Header.js**

```
render() {
   return (<div>
      <DropDown ref="dd"/>
      <a onClick={e => this.refs.dd._toggleDropdown(e)}>Toggle</a>
  </div>)
}
```

If they are totally unrelated you'd better switch from local state to some global state management solution like flux or redux. And make dropdown state to be a part of global application state that any component could change by dispatching corresponding action.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only way to do this kind of thing is by passing the function as props to the Header component. I am not sure about your structures to make a clean snippet with the results. Maybe the design is not being clear enough to make it easy for you.